# How to manage app view when call in progress?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, statusbar

In my iOS app when user attend a call and minimize call to use my app then it shows call in progress in the status bar and shift my app almost 20px down. Is there a way to shorten the app view size 20px at that time and resume it when call is ended?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use application notifications to adjust your view's frame accordingly. Just add observer for `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` or `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` notifications, and when they are called, get the status bar frame from notification object like so:

```
- (void)statisBarFrameWillChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSValue *newFrameValue = [note userInfo][UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];
    //change view's frame here
}
```

and change the frame.

Comment: may i change the size of app window? or i'll have to change the size of all views one by one?